# SQL CASE Usage & Pivot

Tags: sql, oracle

In Table A, I have

```
Cust_ID  Campaign_Date  Campaign_Date1      Campaign_Date2
1          20160101      20160108             20160115
2          20160201      20160208             20160215
```

In Table B,

```
Cust_ID  Bet_Date_Placed_Key  Amount1   Amount2  Amount3
1          20160101     3         4        6
1          20160108     4         5        7
1          20160115     3         4        6
2          20160201     3         4        6
2          20160208     4         5        7
2          20160215     3         4        6
```

Output

```
Cust_ID Campaign_Date  Amount1   Amount2  Amount3   Campaign_Date1 Amount1   Amount2  Amount3  Campaign_Date2 Amount1  Amount2  Amount3

1         20160101       3          4       6           20160108     4        5          7        20160115       3       4         6
2         20160201       3          4       6           20160208     4        5          7        20160215       3       4         6
```

If i use the case statement as mentioned below, think there is a pivot also require on the data with respect to the output

```
select cust_id, 
campaign_date,
(case when campaign_date=Bet_Date_Placed_Key then amount1 else null end) as Amount1,
(case when campaign_date=Bet_Date_Placed_Key then amount2 else null end) as Amount2,
(case when campaign_date=Bet_Date_Placed_Key then amount3 else null end) as Amount3,
```

Comment: Do you have some question?

Comment: DBMS is oracle on which the tables are present

Comment: Hi Giorgi, I am pretty confused on how to code the logic with both case and pivot or any other ways to result the output

Comment: what's exactly the problem you're having? it's unclear what you're asking

Comment: Hi Pablomatico, Sergo answer was correct and solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as `(cust_id, Bet_Date_Placed_Key)` is UNIQUE in `tableB`, just join TableB 3 times

```
 select a.cust_id
 , a.campaign_date, b1.Amount1, b1.Amount2, b1.Amount3
 , a.campaign_date1, b2.Amount1, b2.Amount2, b2.Amount3
 , a.campaign_date2, b3.Amount1, b3.Amount2, b3.Amount3

from tableA a
left join tableB b1 on b1.cust_id=a.cust_id and b1.Bet_Date_Placed_Key  = a.campaign_date
left join tableB b2 on b2.cust_id=a.cust_id and b2.Bet_Date_Placed_Key  = a.campaign_date1
left join tableB b3 on b3.cust_id=a.cust_id and b3.Bet_Date_Placed_Key  = a.campaign_date2
```

Otherwise first aggregate Amounts it tableB by `(cust_id, Bet_Date_Placed_Key)` and then join aggregated  result set the same way.

Comment: correct answer Serg